# Sequelize transaction retry doens't work as expected

Tags: postgresql, transactions, sequelize.js

I don't understand how transaction retry works in `sequelize`.
I am using managed transaction, though I also tried with unmanaged with same outcome

```
await sequelize.transaction({ isolationLevel: Sequelize.Transaction.ISOLATION_LEVELS.REPEATABLE_READ}, async (t) => {

    user = await User.findOne({
        where: { id: authenticatedUser.id },
        transaction: t,
        lock: t.LOCK.UPDATE,
    });    

    user.activationCodeCreatedAt = new Date();
    user.activationCode = activationCode;
    await user.save({transaction: t});
});
```

Now if I run this when the row is already locked, I am getting

```
DatabaseError [SequelizeDatabaseError]: could not serialize access due to concurrent update
```

which is normal. This is my retry configuration:

```
retry: {
    match: [
        /concurrent update/,
    ],
    max: 5
}
```

I want at this point `sequelize` to retry this transaction. But instead I see that right after `SELECT... FOR UPDATE` it's calling again `SELECT... FOR UPDATE`. This is causing another error

```
DatabaseError [SequelizeDatabaseError]: current transaction is aborted, commands ignored until end of transaction block
```

How to use `sequelize`s internal retry mechanism to retry the whole transaction?

Comment: Have you been able to solve it? @Pablo

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't support transaction retry so I ended up implementing my own based on async-retry

Answer (score 0):

**Manual retry workaround function**

Since Sequelize devs simply aren't interested in patching this for some reason after many years, here's my workaround:

```
async function transactionWithRetry(sequelize, transactionArgs, cb) {
  let done = false
  while (!done) {
    try {
      await sequelize.transaction(transactionArgs, cb)
      done = true
    } catch (e) {
      if (
        sequelize.options.dialect === 'postgres' &&
        e instanceof Sequelize.DatabaseError &&
        e.original.code === '40001'
      ) {
        await sequelize.query(`ROLLBACK`)
      } else {
        // Error that we don't know how to handle.
        throw e;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Sample usage:

```
const { Transaction } = require('sequelize');

await transactionWithRetry(sequelize,
  { isolationLevel: Transaction.ISOLATION_LEVELS.SERIALIZABLE },
  async t => {
    const rows = await sequelize.models.MyInt.findAll({ transaction: t })
    await sequelize.models.MyInt.update({ i: newI }, { where: {}, transaction: t })
  }
)
```

The error code `40001` is documented at: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/13/errcodes-appendix.html and it's the only one I've managed to observe so far on Serialization failures: [What are the conditions for encountering a serialization failure?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7705273/what-are-the-conditions-for-encountering-a-serialization-failure) Let me know if you find any others that should be auto looped and I'll patch them in.

Here's a full runnable test for it which seems to indicate that it is working fine: https://github.com/cirosantilli/cirosantilli.github.io/blob/dbb2ec61bdee17d42fe7e915823df37c4af2da25/sequelize/parallel_select_and_update.js

Tested on:

```
    "pg": "8.5.1",
    "pg-hstore": "2.3.3",
    "sequelize": "6.5.1",
```

PostgreSQL 13.5, Ubuntu 21.10.

**Infinite list of related requests**

- https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/issues/1478 from 2014. Original issue was MySQL but thread diverged everywhere.
- https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/issues/8294 from 2017. Also asked on Stack Overflow, but got Tumbleweed badge and the question appears to have been auto deleted, can't find it on search. Mentions MySQL. Is a bit of a mess, as it also includes connection errors, which are not clear retries such as PostgreSQL serialization failures.
- https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/issues/12608 mentions Postgres
- https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/issues/13380 by the OP of this question

**Meaning of `current transaction is aborted, commands ignored until end of transaction block`**

The error is pretty explicit, but just to clarify to other PostgreSQL newbies: in PostgreSQL, when you get a failure in the middle of a transaction, Postgres just auto-errors any following queries until a `ROLLBACK` or `COMMIT` happens and ends the transaction.

The DB client code is then supposed to notice that just re-run the transaction.

These errors are therefore benign, and ideally Sequelize should not raise on them. Those errors are actually expected when using `ISOLATION LEVEL SERIALIZABLE` and `ISOLATION LEVEL REPEATABLE READ`, and prevent concurrent errors from happening.

But unfortunately sequelize does raise them just like any other errors, so it is inevitable for our workaround to have a `while`/`try`/`catch` loop.